# how can I get the current url using protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, testing, protractor

I am testing a website using protractor, and jasmine. I  would like to know the current url in order to verify a test.

I have tried

```
function waitForUrlToChangeTo(urlRegex) {
    var currentUrl;

    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function storeCurrentUrl(url) {
            currentUrl = url;
        }
    ).then(function waitForUrlToChangeTo() {
            return browser.wait(function waitForUrlToChangeTo() {
                return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function compareCurrentUrl(url) {
                    return urlRegex.test(url);
                });
            });
        }
    );
}
```

and I am using this function in this way

```
it('should log', function() {
    //element(by.model('user.username')).sendKeys('asd');
    //element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('asd');
    element(by.linkText('Acceder')).click();
    waitForUrlToChangeTo("http://localhost:9000/#/solicitudes");
});
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you want to just check the current URL, then use [`browser.getCurrentUrl()`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl):

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual("expectedUrl");
```

But, if you need to wait until URL matches a certain value, see the next part of the answer.

---

Here is a working code based on the example provided by the author of the [Expected Conditions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1703):

```
var urlChanged = function(url) {
  return function () {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(actualUrl) {
      return url != actualUrl;
    });
  };
};
```

Usage:

```
element(by.linkText('Acceder')).click();
browser.wait(urlChanged("http://localhost:9000/#/solicitudes"), 5000);
```

Answer (score 43):

[Alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) your answer was very helpful.

But couldn't you just code:

```
 expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('whateverbrowseryouarexpectingtobein');
```

And if this fails, then you know you're going to the wrong place.

Comment: I think the purpose was to wait until the URL matched a certain value, not just to get the value at the given point in time.

Comment: +1 to this answer. The question is "how can I get the current url using protractor?". This is the first google result. I think this answer is more helpful even if it doesn't apply to OP.

Answer (score 10):

Since [Protractor 4.0.0](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlContains) you can now use expected conditions to know when your url changed.

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.urlContains('my-url'), 5000);
```

The asnwer I found comes from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358542/protractor-generic-wait-for-url-to-change), I have no real credits for it. But just in case it help.

[Protractor- Generic wait for URL to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358542/protractor-generic-wait-for-url-to-change)

Comment: This is the correct answer and a much more reliable way to check the URL.