# How can I use protractor to verify an URL?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I would like to *get the current URL using protractor*, and then verify that this URL is the  one that I need. I am using:

```
istheSameURL(url) {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl() === 'http://localhost:9000/#/analysis/62/1';
}
```

However, it is not working.

Comment: What's not working about it? Does browser.getCurrentUrl() not return anything?

Comment: it returns false, although I have called browser.waitForAngular(), so it is supposed in this case the value has to be true.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf debug it a little bit and see what the real url value is at the moment: `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:9000/#/analysis/62/1');`. How does it fail now? Thanks.

Comment: what about `expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()).toEqual(someUrl);`?

Comment: Aaron, it worked. Thank you so much.  If you want you can create  an Answer, and  I can accept it as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `browser.getCurrentUrl()` should be used. It could be that you need to [wait for the URL to be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29398054/771848) using [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait):

```
var urlChanged = function(url) {
  return function () {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(actualUrl) {
      return url != actualUrl;
    });
  };
};

browser.wait(urlChanged("http://localhost:9000/#/analysis/62/1"), 5000);
```

Comment: I am getting a time out error. What if I do not  want to wait I mean if after having used a waitForAngular  I want to check the URL exactly at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

browser.getCurrentUrl() doesn't work with IE 10 if I recall.  If you want to test against IE, you'll have to write some jquery that does that.  I combined both the browser.getCurrentUrl method and the jquery into a function, did an if-check on the browser, and then put that in a common function library.

Comment: This is good to know, though how can you be sure that the OP is using IE? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe - I haven't a clue, but you just *know* management is going to want to make sure it works on IE.