# Protractor- Generic wait for URL to change

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, automation, protractor

In previous questions I have seen that a nice way to wait for the url to change is to use:

```
browser.wait( function() {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        return /myURL/.test(url);
    });
}, 10000, "url has not changed");`
```

But I am trying to have a method that I can pass myURL as a variable (in case I need to use it with other sites) and is not working.

I am trying this in my Page Object file:

```
this.waitUrl = function(myUrl) {
    browser.wait( function(myUrl) {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url, myUrl) {
            return myUrl.test(url);
        });
    }, 10000, "url has not changed");
};
```

Any ideas if this is even possible and how to do it if so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update (July 2016):** with [Protractor 4.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400) you can solve it with [`urlIs`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlIs) and [`urlContains`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.urlContains) built-in Expected Conditions.

---

**Original answer:**

Don't pass `myUrl` inside the `then` function, it is available from the page object function scope:

```
browser.wait(function() {
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        return myUrl.test(url);
    });
}, 10000, "url has not changed");
```

I would though define it as an *Expected Condition*:

```
function waitUrl (myUrl) {
    return function () {
        return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return myUrl.test(url);
        });
    }
}
```

So that you can then use it this way:

```
browser.wait(waitUrl(/my\.url/), 5000);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.
Tried both and got this:
   `Message:
     TypeError: myUrl.test is not a function
   Stacktrace:
     TypeError: myUrl.test is not a function
    at`

Comment: @JamesBe ah, sure, you are using the regular expression match, so your url passed into the expected condition has to be a regular expression. Updated the answer.

Comment: @JamesBe you can also pass in a string and make a regular expression object via `new Regexp(myUrl)`.

Comment: Legend! Thanks alecxe!

Comment: instead of "myUrl.test(url)" you can include anything that resolves to true when myUrl and url match, such as myUrl.include(url)

Answer (score 6):

For those that want an **example** for Protractor 4.0.0 through 5.3.0

You can use "ExpectedConditions" like so...

```
var expectedCondition = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the URL to contain 'login page'.
browser.wait(expectedCondition.urlContains('app/pages/login'), 5000);
```

If you want to validate this with an e2e test.

```
it('should go to login page', function() {
    loginPage.login();
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    browser.wait(EC.urlContains('app/pages/login'), 5000).then(function(result) {
        expect(result).toEqual(true);
    });

});
```